# Custom Conditional Formatting Applying to Range and Self

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I am running into an issue on Google Sheets where the conditional formatting is only applying to the first cell.

Setup

Columns D4:I40 contain a list of names. (This list is currently getting populated by columns via the filter function)

Columns L3:S40 contain will also contain a list of names.

Since L3:S40 is a team selection, I want the D4:I40 range to change colors if there is a match.
[image]

As my formula knowledge is pretty limited, I wasn't able to figure out how to =match a multi-column range. So I resorted to creating multiple conditional formats. However, it does not seem to be working as it is only working for the first cell (John). None of the other names in that column are getting highlighted.

The formula I am using is as follows.
**Apply to range** - D4:D40
**Custom formula is** - `=match(D4,L3:S3,0)`

The thought would be to create this for each team row and then repeat it for each column. If someone knows a better method, please feel free to let me know!

Comment: Can you share with us a sample of your desired output? Is it right for me to assume that you will be applying the conditional formatting per team? And for your sample formula, only John and William will be highlighted in column D?

Comment: Further to @PatrickdC comment, `John` is the name of an Infielder, a Catcher and a Pitcher. Is one to assume that these are the same person or different people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add more information if needed, assuming on what I think you need, you can apply to range D4:I40:

```
=match(D4,TOCOL($L$3:$S$50,1),0)
```

This way, the range of the teams is converted into a single column, and then it can be matched wherever it's found. Change `$L$3:$S$50` to your needed range